# How to copy text from outside application using hotkey?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I have MFC application which gets invoked on hotkey (should be running, just brings it to front), send clipboard data to one of the text box using,

```
SendMessage(hWnd,WM_PASTE,0,0);
```

Everything is working fine till now.

We get new requirement wherein we should be able to copy selected text to clipboard using hot key (**without using Ctrl + C**), and then launch our application.

I tried to use `SendMessage(WM_COPY)`, but does not work.

Please suggest how to get selected text of any other application on clipboard.

Comment: SendMessage accepts a window as its first parameter. You omitted that in your code. Your question is very lacking in detail. We can't tell what you did wrong? Are you dead set on using the clipboard to transfer text? Even though the user is meant to be in control of the clipboard.

Comment: Yes, question is very lacking in detail.

Comment: Your new requirement `we should <...> using hot key <...>, and then launch our application` has an issue: *WHO* is processing your hot key if your app is not running yet?

Comment: @VladFeinstein No one. I need hotkeys to work after my application starts. And that is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I myself got the answer.

I had to use `SendInput`, following is sample code,

```
INPUT ip;
// Set up a generic keyboard event.
ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
ip.ki.time = 0;
ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

// Press the "Ctrl" key
ip.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

// Press the "C" key
ip.ki.wVk = 'C';
ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

// Release the "C" key
ip.ki.wVk = 'C';
ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

// Release the "Ctrl" key
ip.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Comment: You really should bundle up these four input events into one SendInput() call to ensure that they are not interleaved with other keyboard events. Imagine you presses Ctrl+? to invoke your hot key handler, it sends Ctrl DOWN event, at which point you released the Ctrl key (inserting Ctrl UP into the queue), cancelling your action.